# How to pretty-print XML created using boolean condition with ElementMaker

Tags: python, xml, lxml, pretty-print

How can I avoid bad formatting when I do not want to generate **E.note()**?

Right now it all works when condition is **True**, but when it is **False** it introduces space into the xml, which gives bad formatting.

One solution is to use **etree.Subelement(xml, "note")**, but I wanted to avoid this, because it forces me to continue using etree for all subsequent elements.

Python 3 
lxml: 4.5.2

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker 
import lxml.etree as et

E = ElementMaker()

condition = False

xml = E.topic(
    E.first("first"),
    E.note("Text I want sometimes") if condition else "",
    E.third("third")
)

with open("result.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(et.tostring(xml.getroottree(), 
                          pretty_print=True,
                          xml_declaration=True, 
                          encoding='utf-8', 
                          standalone=False))
```

The result I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
<topic><first>first</first><third>third</third></topic>
```

But the result I want is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
<topic>
  <first>first</first>
  <third>third</third>
</topic>
```

Comment: I think you will have to forget `... if condition else ...` and use `subelement()` or `if condition: xml.append(E.note("Text I want sometimes"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this with `... if condition else ...` and you will have to do it in more traditional way

```
xml = E.topic()

xml.append(E.first("first"))

if condition:
    xml.append(E.note("Text I want sometimes"))

xml.append(E.third("third"))
```

eventually

```
xml = E.topic(
    E.first("first"),
    E.third("third")
)

if condition:
    xml.insert(1, E.note('Text I want sometimes'))
```

---

Full working example

```
from lxml.builder import E  # ElementMaker 
import lxml.etree as et

#E = ElementMaker()

# --- functions ---

def display(xml):
    print(et.tostring(xml.getroottree(), 
                          pretty_print=True,
                          xml_declaration=True, 
                          encoding='utf-8', 
                          standalone=False).decode())

def example_0():
    xml = E.topic(
        E.first("first"),
        E.note("Text I want sometimes") if condition else "",
        E.third("third")
    )

    display(xml)
    
def example_1():
    xml = E.topic()

    xml.append(E.first("first"))

    if condition:
        xml.append(E.note("Text I want sometimes"))

    xml.append(E.third("third"))

    display(xml)

def example_2():
    xml = E.topic(
        E.first("first"),
        E.third("third")
    )

    if condition:
        xml.insert(1, E.note('Text I want sometimes'))

    display(xml)
    
# --- main ---

condition = False

example_0()
example_1()
example_2()
```

Comment: Thank you. I really like that you showed both the append and insert version. I will accept this answer.

Comment: I was also thinking about `reduce()` or `[ ... for ... in ... if ...]` to remove `""` before formatting but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If the generated XML is parsed, the pretty-printing works. So a workaround is to add one line of code just before the code that writes the output file:

```
xml = et.fromstring(et.tostring(xml))
```

---

If you want, you can also simplify the code that writes the output file:

```
xml.getroottree().write("result.xml",
                        pretty_print=True,
                        xml_declaration=True, 
                        encoding='utf-8', 
                        standalone=False)
```